# Inverse calculation

Tags: inverse

I am trying to project estimated internal resistance of a battery.

We know that the internal resistance approximately halves as the capacity of the battery doubles.

For example...
A 2AmpHour cell has 8milliOhms of resistance
A 4AmpHour cell has 4milliOhms of resistance
A 8AmpHour cell has 2milliOhms of resistance

What i wonder is how i might put this into a calculation.

I have tried a search, and i do suspect an answer might exist but half the problem might be i am not sure of the terminology.

My appreciation in advance of your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that in all three cases you provide,
milli-Ohms * AmpHrs = 16 ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $b$ be the capacity in ampere hours and $r$ be the resistance. Then $br = 16, r = 16/b, b = 16/r$.